# How to solve the differential equation $y'=(x+y)/(x-y)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question, $y'=\frac{x+y}{x-y}$ is asking to be differentiated, but isn't $y' =\frac{dy}{dx}$ so I'd have to integrate.

Comment: Please check and clarify. Are you being asked to compute the second derivative or are you asked to solve this differential equation?

Comment: My homework is in russian and I had to translate, it says Determine the type of data(what can this possibly mean?) and solve differential equations in the first order. Technically isnt y' already in the first? Judging by that I think they want me to integrate, would you say so?

Comment: if you don't need to solve it, let me know i can delete my answer.

Comment: I do need a solution, but moreso I want a clear step by step explanation, possibly an ELI5 (would be VERY thankful for that)

Comment: This is a homogeneous DE. Abel has it nailed.

Answer (score 6):

here is one way to do this. use the change of variable $$m = \frac yx, y = mx, y' = m'x + m.$$ you can transform $y' = \frac{x+y}{x-y}$ to a separable $$m'x + m = \frac{1+m}{1-m} \to x\frac{dm}{dx} = \frac{1+m}{1-m} - m=\frac{1+m^2}{1-m} $$ so you have $$\frac{(1-m)\, dm}{1+m^2} = \frac{dx}{x} $$ you can take it from here.

Comment: You killed me my friend. I'm fairly new to this, and I do understand the concept of changing variables but I notice y'=m'x+m so automatically I need to know the derivative of y/x in m', which just complicates things in my opinion.

Comment: @stan, you need to remember that $m$ is now a function of $x.$ that is why i used the product rule $dy = d(xm) = x \, dm + m \, dx.$ the gives $y' = xm' + m$

Comment: Is there a method without changing variables?

Comment: @stan, i doubt it. i tried to see if this is an exact differential. it is not. i can't come up with a simple integrating factor. if you know little bit of linear algebra, you can use linear algebra to get a solution. you can also use the polar coordinates but that involves a change of variable again. i think what i have posted is, i think, the most direct method.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate again to get the second derivative

$$y''= \dfrac{d(y')}{dx}.$$

Comment: But I need to integrate it back to y I believe